# I'm unable to save camera captured image no matter what I do. How do I do it?

Tags: java, android, android-camera, android-file

I've followed everything to the dot from [this](https://developer.android.com/training/camera/photobasics) official Android website.

I've stored the `createTempFile()`'s path in `currentImagePath` in my code. Printing that shows the path. However, it seems like there's no data at that path.

My logic is to copy data from that path to a permanent path.

```
btnTakePic.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                captureImage(v);
                /*try {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                }
                catch (InterruptedException e)
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }*/

                //System.out.println(currentImagePath);
                File from = new File(currentImagePath);
                File storageFileDir = getFilesDir();
                byte[] bArray = new byte[(int) from.length()];
                try{
                    fi = new FileInputStream(from);
                    fi.read(bArray);
                    fi.close();

                }catch(IOException ioExp){
                    ioExp.printStackTrace();
                }
                File picStorageDir = new File(storageFileDir,"myPics");
                perStorageDir = picStorageDir;
                if(!picStorageDir.isDirectory())
                {
                    picStorageDir.mkdirs();
                }
                System.out.println(perStorageDir.getAbsolutePath());
                System.out.println("From length: "+from.length());
                try {
                    String[] t = currentImagePath.split("/"); // this is just to get image name
                    File temp = new File(picStorageDir,t[t.length-1]); // this is to set file with image name
                    ff = new FileOutputStream(temp);

                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                try {
                    ff.write(bArray);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
});
```

Below is `captureImage()` method

```
public void captureImage(View view)
    {
        Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

        if(cameraIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager())!=null)
        {
            File imageFile = null;
            try {
                imageFile = getImageFile();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            if(imageFile!=null)
            {
                Uri imageUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(this, "com.example.android.fileprovider", imageFile);
                cameraIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, imageUri);
                startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, IMAGE_REQUEST);
            }
            System.out.println("imageFile length:"+imageFile.length());

        }

    }
```

This is the log output

```
2020-04-30 14:19:32.646 31226-31226/com.example.ccalculator I/System.out: currImPath: /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.example.ccalculator/files/Pictures/jpg_20200430_1419032_793088582.jpg
2020-04-30 14:19:32.657 31226-31226/com.example.ccalculator I/System.out: imageFile length:0
2020-04-30 14:19:32.657 31226-31226/com.example.ccalculator I/System.out: /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.example.ccalculator/files/Pictures/jpg_20200430_1419032_793088582.jpg
2020-04-30 14:19:32.658 31226-31226/com.example.ccalculator I/System.out: permanent storage dir: /data/user/0/com.example.ccalculator/files/myPics
2020-04-30 14:19:32.658 31226-31226/com.example.ccalculator I/System.out: From length: 0
```

At this point, I have yet to capture the image from the app. So I thought maybe once I capture the image the data will be stored at the respective paths. I tried adding `Thread.sleep(1000);` but even that doesn't help.

Comment: `My logic is to copy data from that path to a permanent path.`. Both paths are equally permanent. But do not copy before taking a picture goes ok. And indeed you have to use onAcyivityResult to do something with the picture taken.

Comment: `followed everything to the dot` Well no, otherwise you would have used onActivityResult().

Answer (score 0):

The capture comes back on a callback i.e. `startActivityForResult` doesn't pause the thread, so add something like...

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == IMAGE_REQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
```

Put your code to deal with the new image in the callback.